# Is there a way to efficiently sum a pandas data frame column up to row for the whole column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to create a new column based of column_1 that on each row of index i sums up all of column_1 up to index i.

I've figured out a way to do it by grabbing the row and summing it up to that index on each row:

```
column_array = np.array(df['column_1'])
df['new column'] = [column_array[:n].sum() for n in range(len(column_array)]'
```

But doing it like so requires to sum from the start on every entry, I'm working on a large amount of large data frames so I'd like an efficient solution as right now this summing operation is the bottle-neck of my script.

Comment: [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html).

Comment: Even look at [`np.cumsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html#numpy-cumsum)

Answer (score 0):

Like BigBen said, `cumsum()` does exactly this. Looking at your own example, you have a shifted column. If this is indeed what you want, you can use `shift()` as well. Try running the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['column_1'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
df['cumsum_column'] = df['column_1'].shift().cumsum(axis=0)


column_array = np.array(df['column_1'])
df['your_new_column'] = [column_array[:n].sum() for n in range(len(column_array))]

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`cumsum()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) function of `pandas` to get the  cumulative sum of data elements. Try the following:

```
df['new_column'] = df['column_1'].cumsum()
```

Comment: Yes, I was trying to make edits in the code posted in the question. I'll edit my post. Thank you for bringing it to my notice

Answer (score -1):

I would not use comprehension on this task personally. Iterate through the column and keep track of sum then simply append to your new column every iteration.

```
column_array = np.array(df['column_1'])
sum_column = [None] * len(column_array)
summ = 0
for i, col in enumerate(column_array):
    summ += col
    sum_column[i] = summ
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).